# LazyLoading Component in angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am following the following blog for lazy loading a directive in angularJs
[Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838402/Lazy-loading-directives-in-AngularJS-the-easy-way)

what they do is add a script in head with the src as directive path which is on server and make directive tags , compile and add it

How to do this in angular 4

```
 {path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' }
```

lazy loadin in angular happens like this.
bt that path is static

how to dynamically give path to loadchildren

following is the way mentioned on this blog [link](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/09/30/lazy-loading-components-routes-services-router-angular-2/)
bt it might be deprecated.

```
@RouteConfig([


 { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home' },
  new AsyncRoute({
    path: '/about',
    loader: () => System.import('./components/about/about').then(m => m.About),
    name: 'about'
  })
])
```

Comment: put code here. what you trying?.

Comment: see official site https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#!#lazy-load

Comment: { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' },

they use this to lazyload, bt the path is static. i cant give static path. the path has to be given dynamically.

Comment: Please post your code. Nobody can help you if you don't

Comment: @brijmcq edited

Answer (score 2):

create one routing module for that for example

import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

```
export const CrisisRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: RootComponent, // set here your parent component.. which is you put <routoutlet>
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/home',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
               path: 'home', 
               component: HomeComponent
            },
        ]
    }
];
export const CricidRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild(CrisisRoute);
```

**Load your module**

created `CrisisModule` module file and add `CricidRoutingModule` into import.
and then you can load it into routing module like

```
{path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' }
```

Comment: crisis module is the module i want to lazy load. there might be many more components , say crisis1 , crisis2 etc  i cant hardcode there path in loadchildren,

i want to create that path in code and provide it to load children

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
    import { MarketsComponent } from './base/markets.component';
    import { SportsComponent } from './base/sports.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/markets', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'markets', component: MarketsComponent },
      { path: 'sports', component: SportsComponent },
      { path: 'weather', loadChildren: './weather/weather.module#WeatherModule' },
      { path: 'currency', loadChildren: './currency/currency.module#CurrencyModule' } 
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
        {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules}
        )
      ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {

    }
```

This will load modules as lazy load. Try it from My github repo
https://github.com/aryanhussain/loadingInNg

Comment: i cant hardcode the path of module  ex:'./currency/currency.module#CurrencyModule'

this will be created dynamically .
as in the user will click on a button , on clicking we will get weather , currency, etc from this we will make the path.

is thr a way to give this path also dynamically

Answer (score -1):

You're following the outdated blog. Keep up-to-date with the latest stuff. Try [this](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial.
For lazy loading take a look [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-load-feature-modules-in-angular4/index.html)